# MY React app opens Index.html and not App.js while using npm run (blank page)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I am working on a React app. It used to open, but closing my app, taking a break and reopening it again localhost:3000 is showing a blank page from the index.html file, and not the app.js.

In gitbash I used `cd` to go to the file where the app is located and used `npm start`

the app was initially created with the create-react-app command

there it says that the webpack was compiled succesfully.

However, I get served a blank page. My index.html file is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work%20Sans:300,500" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:600" />
    <title>Jammming</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

and my app.js code (located at src/Components/App/App.js) is the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import { SearchBar } from '../SearchBar/SearchBar.js';
import { SearchResults } from '../SearchResults/SearchResults.js';
import { Playlist } from '../Playlist/Playlist.js';


class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {
     searchResults: [{ name: 'name1', artist: 'artist1', album: 'album1', id: 1 }, 
     { name: 'name2', artist: 'artist2', album: 'album2', id: 2 }, 
     { name: 'name3', artist: 'artist3', album: 'album3', id: 3 }]
   };
 };

 return() {(
   <div className = "App" >
     <header className="App-header">
       <div>
         <h1>Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing</h1>
         <div class="App">
           <SearchBar />
           <div className="App-playlist">
             <SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults}/>
             <Playlist />
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <p>
         Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to check check.
       </p>
       <a
         className="App-link"
         href="https://reactjs.org"
         target="_blank"
         rel="noopener noreferrer"
       >
         Learn React
       </a>
     </header>
   </div>
 )};
}

export default App;
```

and this is the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "jammming",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

many thanks!

Comment: Hi Rikkie, can you also post your package.json scripts part and did you create your app with create-react-app or similars? App.js file (along with index.js) should be in the root folder of your application, usually. The index.html file should be in the public folder instead.

Comment: Hi 404 and Fide, I added the package.json file here. I created the app with create-react-app. @Fide, I tried to add that with the correct path but it is not working it seems.

Comment: Can you add your index.js file to the question?

Comment: I had to restart the whole thing, which was also a good lesson in using a GIT repository properly, because I neglected to do that..  Oh well, that's how you learn I guess :)